# go exec with <(..) argument

Tags: go, exec

I'm trying to get the equivalent using exec

```
diff <(echo "foo") <(echo "bar")
```

which produces:

```
1c1
< foo
---
> bar
```

But when I try:

```
cmd := exec.Command("diff", "<(echo foo)", "<(echo bar)")
```

The output is:

```
exit status 2
diff: <(echo foo): No such file or directory
diff: <(echo bar): No such file or directory
```

Comment: That's a very shell specific thing you can't just exec `diff` and expect shell parsing of the arguments. You could exec `bash` (since `<(command)` is a bash-ism) with a "-c" argument, or you could build Go `exec.Cmd`'s for foo, bar, and diff and connect them up with pipes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FUZxxl's answer is simple, but it requires the use of bash. Bash is not really cross platform and as an interpreter is open to code injection. I will first describe a way to replicate this with Go, then describe the answer git uses.

The <(echo foo) does two things in bash. First, it creates a file descriptor to be passed to the command being called. The second thing it does is pass /dev/fd/n as an argument. For confirmation, try:

```
echo <(echo foo) <(echo bar)
```

Echo ignores the fds and just prints the file descriptor as a string.

The following Go code will do something similar:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("diff", "/dev/fd/3", "/dev/fd/4")

    foo, err := readerFile(strings.NewReader("foo\n"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer foo.Close()

    bar, err := readerFile(strings.NewReader("bar\n"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer bar.Close()

    cmd.ExtraFiles = []*os.File{foo, bar}

    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func readerFile(r io.Reader) (*os.File, error) {
    reader, writer, err := os.Pipe()

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    go func() {
        io.Copy(writer, r)
        writer.Close()
    }()

    return reader, nil
}
```

Obviously, this will only work on Unix like systems and is therefore not very cross platform. It is immune to code injection though.

---

## GIT's way

Git just makes temporary files and then compares them. This is extremely cross platform and immune to injections. Just use [ioutil.TempFile](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempFile) to create both the files and then run `exec.Command("diff", file1, file2)`.

Comment: One change that'd make this a better answer would be to not hard code the the descriptor numbers in the diff command line.  Instead, call the Fd() method on the pipes and build the paths appropriately.

Comment: When using Cmd.ExtraFiles, the FDs seen by the child are 3+i where i is the index of the file in the ExtraFiles slice. Hardcoding is the only way. http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd

Answer (score 3):

The `<(echo foo)` syntax is interpreted by the shell, `sh` or `bash`. The function `exec.Command` does not invoke the shell on the arguments you provide, it directly executes a process. If you want to invoke the shell, then invoke the shell:

```
exec.Command("bash", "-c", "diff <(echo foo) </echo bar)")
```

In this example I use `bash` as on many systems, `sh` does not implement the `<(cmd)` syntax. Try to use `sh` whenever possible to increase the portability of your applications.